# Как найти точки, определяющие контур прямолинейного (ортогонального) многоугольника?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, canvas

Я пытаюсь найти способ определения контура прямолинейного многоугольника. Не могу найти алгоритм подходящий для этой задачи.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении нужно копать?

На изображении ниже, показано, чего мне хотелось бы достичь. 
[image]

Comment: Каким образом задана область многоугольника? На рисунке не совсем попятно какие именно точки нужны

Comment: Нужны все точки ограничивающие многоугольник.

Comment: @Openmen А как вы задаете эти точки? Это массив целочисленных точек? Многоугольник всегда выпуклый или нет? Точки всегда задаются подряд? Привидите хотя бы пример начальных данных. Просто судя по вашему рисунку, надо найти крайние точки, у которой не существует соседа - это и есть граничная точка, а все внутренние - удаляем. Готово.

Comment: Нужно то же самое? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496421/orthogonal-hull-algorithm/46780595#46780595